# Create Icon view for specific text in Excel

Tags: excel

This is not using the conditional formatting and I would seek for advise anyone know how to create icon as below with specific text in excel?

When Text "R" then show the correct icon as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The char R for the font in Wingdings2 is a ticked check box.

Change the font for that cell to Wingdings2:

[image: Image of R in Wingdings2 font]

To note, in your screenshot of the drop down menu, Q is a crossed checkbox and £ is a blank checkbox.

Comment: Awesome, I have try and is work. Thanks