# Is there a way I can simulate a right click check box?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I’m working on an Excel workbook that automatically populates a PDF with the information present in an Excel sheet. I can get everything in the Excel sheet to populate the PDF document except in the case when it comes to a check box, as you can see in the picture if CJ2 were true it would populate the check box in the PDF, I can get it to populate the PDF with regular words like names. I just want to know if I can do something like if this says true then prompt a right click or a check box.

**Check Box Example**

[image: Check Box Example]

**Excel Sheet to Populate PDF Check Box**

[image: Excel Sheet to Populate PDF Check Box]

````
Enum W32_Window_State
    Show_Normal = 1
    Show_Minimized = 2
    Show_Maximized = 3
    Show_Min_No_Active = 7
    Show_Default = 10
End Enum
 
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Function OpenURL(URL As String, WindowState As W32_Window_State) As Boolean
 
' Opens passed URL with default application, or Error Code (<32) upon error
 
    Dim lngHWnd As Long
    Dim lngReturn As Long
 
    lngReturn = ShellExecute(lngHWnd, "open", URL, vbNullString, _
        vbNullString, WindowState)
   
    OpenURL = (lngReturn > 32)
End Function
Sub PDFTemplate()
Dim PDFFldr As FileDialog
Set PDFFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With PDFFldr
    .Title = "Select PDF file to attach'"
    .Filters.Add "PDF Type Files", "*.pdf", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection
    ActiveSheet.Range("D11").Value = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NoSelection:
End Sub
Sub SavePDFFolder()
Dim PDFFldr As FileDialog
Set PDFFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With PDFFldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSel:
    ActiveSheet.Range("D16").Value = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NoSel:
End Sub
Sub CreatePDFForms()
Dim PDFTemplateFile, NewPDFName, SavePDFFolder, FirstName As String
Dim EplyrName As String
Dim c As Range
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long


With Sheets("Macro")
    LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row  'LastRow
    PDFTemplateFile = .Range("D11").Value 'Template File Name
    SavePDFFolder = .Range("D16").Value 'Save PDF Folder
    OpenURL "" & PDFTemplateFile & "", Show_Maximized
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00006
End With

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row  'LastRow
    For CustRow = 2 To 2 'LastRow
    FirstName = .Range("T" & CustRow).Value 'LastName
    EplyrName = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value 'Employeer Name
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    
    Application.SendKeys FirstName, True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("U" & CustRow).Value, True 'Middle Name
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("V" & CustRow).Value, True 'Last Name
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("S" & CustRow).Value, True 'Social Security
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("B" & CustRow).Value, True 'Name of Employer
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("A" & CustRow).Value, True 'EID
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("X" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Address
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("F" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employer Address
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("D" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employer Phone Number
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AA" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee City
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AB" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee State
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AC" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee State
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("I" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employer City
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("J" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employer State
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("K" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employer Zip
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AI" & CustRow).Value, True 'Plan Start
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AJ" & CustRow).Value, True 'All 12 Month Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AK" & CustRow).Value, True 'Jan Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AL" & CustRow).Value, True 'Feb Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AM" & CustRow).Value, True 'March Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AN" & CustRow).Value, True 'April Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AO" & CustRow).Value, True 'May Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AP" & CustRow).Value, True 'June Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AQ" & CustRow).Value, True 'July Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AR" & CustRow).Value, True 'August Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AS" & CustRow).Value, True 'September Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AT" & CustRow).Value, True 'October Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AU" & CustRow).Value, True 'November Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AV" & CustRow).Value, True 'December Offer of Coverage
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AW" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share 12 Months
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AX" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share Jan
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AY" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share Feb
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("AZ" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share March
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BA" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share April
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BB" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share May
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BC" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share June
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BD" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share July
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BE" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share August
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BF" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share September
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BG" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share October
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BH" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share November
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BI" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Share December
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BJ" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For all 12 months
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BK" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For Jan
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BL" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For Feb
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BM" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For March
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BN" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For April
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BO" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For May
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BP" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For June
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BQ" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For July
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BR" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For August
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BS" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For September
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BT" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For October
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BU" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For November
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BV" & CustRow).Value, True 'Safe Harbor Code For December
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BW" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for all 12 months
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BX" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for Jan
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BY" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for Feb
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BZ" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for March
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
                
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("CA" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for April
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("CB" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for May
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("CC" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for June
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("CD" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for July
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("CE" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for August
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("CF" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for September
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("CG" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for October
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("BH" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for November
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys .Range("CI" & CustRow).Value, True 'Zip code for December
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    'Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    'Application.SendKeys .Range("CJ" & CustRow).Value, True 'Part iii Check box
    'Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CJ" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = True Then Application.SendKeys "{Space}", True 'Part iii Check box
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
        
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CQ" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = True Then Application.SendKeys "{Space}", True 'Covered all 12 months?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CR" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = True Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered January?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CS" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = True Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered February?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CT" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered March?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CU" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered April?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CV" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered May?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CW" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered June?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CX" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered July?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CY" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered August?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CZ" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered September?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("DA" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered October?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c

    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("DB" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered November?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("DC" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = "TRUE" Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered December?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c```
````

Comment: Would using a different font in the pdf to simulate a check box work? use character R  to represent a check box with the wingdings2 font, in the PDF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76379171/create-icon-view-for-specific-text-in-excel/76379608#76379608

Comment: Try sending a space - https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/sendkeys-for-a-tick-box.141827/

Comment: @5202456 Tried it but it did not work, thank you tho.

Comment: @TimWilliams Would you say something like this? 

```If Range("CJ").Value = "TRUE" Then
    Application.SendKeys.Send (" "), True
ElseIf Range("CJ").Value = "FALSE" Then
     Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
End If
End Sub```

Comment: Why not try that?  I don't have your PDF form to test with...

Comment: Each Tab moves you to the next checkbox, so you always need the Tab, but only send a space if the cell value is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range
    AppActivate "2022 Form 1095-C - Adobe Acrobat Pro"
    
    For Each c In Range("A1:A12").Cells
        Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
        If c.Value = True Then Application.SendKeys " ", True 'Covered January?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Input range:
[image]

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

**EDIT:** a few suggestions for making your code easier to manage:

A few utility methods for handling the SendKeys

```
Sub DoTabs(Optional numTabs As Long = 1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To numTabs
        Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Next i
End Sub

'Enter some text `txt`, preceded by one (default) or more Tab characters
Sub SendIt(txt As String, Optional PreTabs As Long = 1)
    If PreTabs > 0 Then DoTabs PreTabs
    If Len(txt) > 0 Then
        Application.SendKeys txt, True
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    End If
End Sub

'Special field type - check box if value `v` is true
Sub CheckBox(v As Boolean, Optional PreTabs As Long = 1)
    SendIt IIf(v, " ", ""), PreTabs
End Sub
```

Then your code can be more like this:

```
    Dim rw As Range, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, r As Long
    
    '...
    '...
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    For r = 2 To ws.Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row
        With ws.Rows(r)
        
        FirstName = .Range("T1").Value 'LastName
        EplyrName = .Range("B1").Value 'Employeer Name
        
        SendIt FirstName, 3 '3 tabs first...
        SendIt .Range("U1").Value 'defaults to 1 tab before value
        SendIt .Range("V1").Value  'Last Name
        SendIt .Range("S1").Value 'Social Security
        SendIt .Range("B1").Value 'Name of Employer
        SendIt .Range("A1").Value 'EID
        SendIt .Range("X1").Value 'Employee Address
        SendIt .Range("F1").Value 'Employer Address
        SendIt .Range("D1").Value 'Employer Phone Number
        SendIt .Range("AA1").Value 'Employee City
        SendIt .Range("AB1").Value 'Employee State
        SendIt .Range("AC1").Value 'Employee State
        SendIt .Range("I1").Value  'Employer City
        SendIt .Range("J1").Value  'Employer State
        SendIt .Range("K1").Value  'Employer Zip
        SendIt .Range("AI1").Value 'Plan Start
        '....
        '....
        CheckBox .Range("CJ1").Value 'sets checkbox if cell value is True
```

Comment: Would there be a way to make it go one by one? I can’t run a separate sub while the PDF is open since it populates information before it gets to the checkboxes. 

`Dim c As Range 
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long 

With Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row 'LastRow 
For CustRow = 2 To LastRow 
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    For Each c In Range("CQ" & CustRow).Cells
        If c.Value = True Then Application.SendKeys (" "), True 'Covered all 12 months?
        Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Next c`

Comment: Please edit your question if you want to add code.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77128439/edit   I'm not sure what you mean by "one by one"

Comment: Hey, I apologize for the late response, just updated the code. One by one as in instead of having a given range ex. A1:A12 it goes from A2,B2,C2. I tried adding a dynamic range in rows in my code since the amount of inputs may change.

Comment: I can't tell what "the amount of inputs may change" really means in your specific use case - I don't have either your Excel file or the PDF you're using.  The code I posted was just a simple example to show how to check the boxes....  You can switch the range to a row instead of a column and it doesn't really change much.

Comment: By the amount of inputs I meant. One day it may be 10 the other day it may be 100, I did change it to a row in my code. But the space send key is not registering I've tried both (" ") and {Space} but honestly it might just be that I'm using PDF Xchange since when I actually hit my spacebar it marks the checkbox but not when I do the SendKey promt.

Comment: I guess that's now *3* things I don't have to test with...

Comment: Found a funny way to work around the space bar send key. When a word in the text has a space in it then that will trigger the checkbox because of the present space. So I just changed "TRUE" to "TRUE TRUE" with the space added :). A simple solution for now. Thank you for all your help!